# How export my library with paths using webpack?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-4, tsx

Actually my library export the resources to be imported that way:

```
import { fooComponent } from 'my-library/lib/components'
import { fooHook } from 'my-library/lib/hooks'
```

What do I need to change in my `webpack.config.js` to can import my resources that way?

```
import { fooComponent } from 'my-library/components'
import { fooHook } from 'my-library/hooks'
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
  ...
  entry: {
    components: './src/components/index.js',
    hooks: './src/hooks/index.js',
    index: './src/index.js',
    services: './src/services/index.js',
    templates: './src/templates/index.js'
  },
  ...
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    globalObject: 'typeof self !== "undefined" ? self : this',
    library: 'my-library',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    path: path.join(fileRoot, 'lib'),
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
```

Modify `path: path.join(fileRoot, 'lib')` to `path: path.join(fileRoot, '')` is not an option, because I need have a distribution path.

Is this possible solve this problem using TypeScript or Webpack?

Comment: @PlayMa256 in the OP's config, webpack doesn't merge everything together. Check again the `entry` and `output.filename` values in the webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is not an issue with Webpack. Webpack will bundle everything, according to your config, in `./lib/[name].js`, and that is exacly what you want, since you need a distribution path. So Webpack's job ends there.

Enter the role of [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json), which defines which packages are available and where. Let's look into two different codes and what happens under the hood (oversimplification):

`import lib from 'my-lib';`

1. look up the script designated in 'node_modules/my-lib/package.json#main`
2. import all as `lib` from this script

`import { someComponent } from 'my-lib/lib/components';`

1. look up 'node_modules/my-lib/lib/components.js`, or`node_modules/my-lib/lib/components/index.js`
2. import `someComponent` from this script

So, there doesn't seems to be any possible package configuration that would simply allow you to remove the `lib` from your imports. But, is it that big of a problem? That's just three letters

Comment: No itsn't a big problem of course, but... Are four caracthers for any import on this library. You answer don't help me so much. In any moment I say that this is a webpack issue, but I don't see how configure it correctly to work how expected.

Comment: If isn't possible do what I want using webpack, maybe changing some in package.json, or creating typescript configs this can be possible. I don't no.